# Pattern match DateTime.DayOfWeek F#

Tags: .net, datetime, f#, pattern-matching

i want to extraxt the number of the day from DateTime.DayOfWeek

`match DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek with`

FSI output is something like:

`val it : DayOfWeek = Thursday {value__ = 4;}`

but I dont know with what to match to get the number. I'm trying not to match the ToString()-Version. Is there a possibility?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want the number for day of the week: `int DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, there seems to be a gap in the [FSharp spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf). It is not clear if an `enum` value translates directly to a [Simple Constant Pattern](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A304%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C549%2C0%5D) or if it is considered a [Literal Pattern](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A309%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C678%2C0%5D).

Nevertheless, matching it is straightforward by using the enum's field name:

```
match DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek with
| DayOfWeek.Thursday -> ...
```